# Расшифровать сообщение, зашифрованное с помощью разных систем счисления

Tags: криптография

1) 11 0F 13 10 29 1F 19 06 17 0E 01 20 02 06 08 0F 16 01 18 0E 15 12 19 1D

2) 18 18 09 13 28 03 01 0E 09 06

Известно, что при шифровании использовалось несколько систем счисления. Первое сообщение удалось расшифровать – «КОМПЬЮТЕРНАЯБЕЗОПАСНОСТЬ». Как расшифровать второе сообщение?

Comment: Криптография 80-й level :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сообщения зашифрованы номером буквы в русском алфавите, и чередуются 10-чная и 16 ричная.

18 - десятичная. 18 буква это С

18 16-ричная, это 24 буква, это Ч

09 - 9 буква И

13 - 19 буква Т

28 - 28 буква Ы

03 - 3 буква В

01 - 1 буква А

0E - 14 буква Н
09 - 9 буква И
06 - Е

Итак, мы получили слово СЧИТЫВАНИЕ. Здесь Е=Ё, всего 32 буквы.